# Static type checking for Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, typechecking, mypy

I just installed Eclipse Photon and PyDev 6.4.3 with Python 3.6. I'm now trying to figure out how to get static type checking working (e.g. with [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)). Is this possible in Eclipse? Is there a plugin other than PyDev that'll handle this? I've hit a dead end at this point with internet searches.

Comment: As I understand it (and I may be wrong, or out of date), the general PyDev strategy is to not do the kind of "partial integration" for tools that most other IDEs do, and instead fully integrate things whenever possible (e.g., the way you can optionally enable PyLint in the static analyzer), or leave you to run them as external tools that just generate "some output, whatever" for PyDev to show you without trying to understand it (e.g., the way you can't use PyFlakes in place of PyLint). So, if you can't find an option to enable mypy in the analyzer, you can likely only use it as a generic tool.

Comment: Also, IIRC, the PyDev authors didn't really like PEP 484, and wanted to encourage people to write static type checkers that used Sphinx-format comments instead (which would then integrate nicely into the Sphinx-format type-driven code completion in PyDev). I don't know if they've changed their minds since then, but if not, I wouldn't be surprised if mypy integration is way down their list of things to consider doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not there (and yes, I have plans to add it as an external checker using mypy -- is is the case for pylint -- it's just not there yet... I'm very time constrained right now, but it's close to the top of my todo list).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny thanks for the info; I'll keep an eye on the update notes.